# how to show values from JSON without show parent with angular 5 and IONIC3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular5

I am triying to print value from Json without parent.

I have this JSON:

```
[
    {
      "companies": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Prueba",
        "company_number": "23423423A",
        "latitude": 241241.12,
        "longitude": 213213.12,
        "country": "ES"
      },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Prueba2",
          "company_number": "23423423A",
          "latitude": 241241.12,
          "longitude": 213213.12,
          "country": "US"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Prueba3",
          "company_number": "23423423AB",
          "latitude": 241241.19,
          "longitude": 213213.20,
          "country": "US"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "centers":[
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Prueba4",
          "center_number": "23423423A",
          "latitude": 241241.12,
          "longitude": 213213.12,
          "country": "ES"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Prueba5",
          "center_number": "23423423A",
          "latitude": 241241.12,
          "longitude": 213213.12,
          "country": "US"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I've write this with angular in my ionic project:

```
 <ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let p of profiles; let i=index">
<p>{{i}}</p> <!-- this works fine-->
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let s of p[i]; let i2=index">
      <p>{{p[i][i2][name]</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-item>
```

I want to achieve this :

- Prueba
- Prueba2
- Prueba3
- Prueba4
- Prueba5

Can I achieve this direct in front or should I process that before?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Changing `{{p[i][i2][name]` for `{{p[i][i2].name}}` should make this work I think.

Answer (score 0):

`ngFor` can't iterate over your structure. You must flatten it first.

Assuming the array is called `arr`:

```
const newArr = [...arr[0].companies, ...arr[1].centers];
```

Now `newArr` contains the five objects you want and you can use `ngFor` over it.